# How to expose a function that takes two input files as a REST resource?

Tags: rest

I need to expose a function, let's say `compute` that takes two input files: a `plan` file and a `system` file. The `compute` function uses to `system` file to see whether the plan in the `plan` file can be executed or not. It produces an `output` file containing the result of this check including recommendations for the plan.

I need to expose this functionality in a REST architecture and have no influence on the compute function itself (it is being developed by another organization). I can control the interface through which it is accessed.

What would be a recommended way to expose this functionality in a REST architecture?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a **/compute** resource that accepts **multipart/form-data** and POST your files to this. There is a fairly good and complete form based example of just such a REST service [here](http://technopaper.blogspot.com/2009/03/multiple-file-upload-using-restful-web.html)